# Nested for loop in bash not iterating properly?

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to scripting/programming/everything and can't seem to figure out this bash script/loop I am trying to iterate.

I have a directory called "folder", in which there are many subdirectories which each contain files that I would like to echo (for now)

I have this, but it doesn't seem to print the files within the subdirectories but instead prints the subdirectories themselves. How would I alter the script to make this work?

```
for directory in *;
do
        for thing in $directory 
        do
                echo $thing
        done
done
```

Comment: Don't you want `${directory}/*`?  Or perphaps `(cd "$directory"; for thing in *; do echo $thing; done;)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop itself doesn't traverse a file system; it only iterates over a sequence of strings. You need to iterate over the result of a pathname expansion for the second loop.

```
for directory in *;
do
    for thing in "$directory"/*
    do
        echo "$thing"
    done
done
```

You can do this with one loop with a more complex pattern:

```
for thing in */*; do
    echo "$thing"
done
```

Comment: By no loop, do you mean something like `some_command */*`? I'm assuming that the body of the inner loop is more complicated than a single built-in command, in which case this would have problems with large sets of matches.

Answer (score 1):

Bash version 4.0 adds a new globbing option called `globstar` which treats the pattern `**` differently when it's set.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
for file in folder/** # with '**'  bash recurses all the directories
do
  echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: The array is extraneous, and possibly a drain on memory; you can iterate over the pattern directly, which (I think) doesn't need to store the full match in memory.